# Not able to call JQuery On Submit function from inside a modal form

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to call a Jquery function on submission of a form which lies inside a modal. The modal itself is in another file test1.php. But the jquery function is not getting called

This is my HTML File:

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Job Entry</title>
            <link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"  
            type="text/css">
            <link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">           
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-
            scale=1">
        </head>

        <body>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-push-1">
                       <a href="test1.php" id="addNewCP" name="addNewCP" 
                       class="form-control btn btn-success " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addNewCPModal"  >
                           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> &nbsp;Add CP</a> 
                    </div> 



            <!--Modal for addition of new CP details begins here-->
            <div class="modal fade text-center" id="addNewCPModal">
                <form method="post" id="enterCPDetails" name="enterCPDetails">
                <div class="modal-dialog ">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                     <!-- Rest of the content of this Modal lies in test1.php -->    
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <script src="js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
            <script src="js/custom1.js"></script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

The modal lies in separate page titled test1.php:

```
<div class="modal-header" style="height:55px; background-color: #122b40; color:#fff; padding:10px">
    <button type="button" class="close" style="color:white" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> &times; </button>
    Electronics Quality Control Division <br> Data Management System 
</div>

    <div class="modal-body"> 
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                <span class="default-textSetting" > Job No: </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="CP No" name="newCPNo" id="newCPNo" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><br>    
                <table  id="newCPDetailsTable" class=" table table-stripped table-condensed table-bordered" >
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ICP No. </th>
                            <th>Substrate No. </th> 
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input size="16" type="text" class="form-control"  name="icp1" id="icp1" required/></td>
                            <td><input size="16"  type="text" class="form-control" name="subid1" id="subid1" required/></td>
                            <td colspan="2"><a  href="JavaScript:void(0);" onclick="addRow()" style="color:green" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus ">&nbsp;</a>
                                            <a  href="JavaScript:void(0);"   style="color:red" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle "></a>
                            </td>

                        </tr> 

                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <input id="cntTableRows" name="cntTableRows" type="hidden" />
    </div><!--modal body ends here-->

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close </button>    
        <button type="submit" name="newCPDetailSubmit" id="newCPDetailSubmit" class="btn btn-default" >Save</button>
    </div>
```

My Jquery function is as follows:

```
 $(function(){
        $("#enterCPDetails").on("submit", function (event) {
        alert("Hello");
       });
    });
```

What wrong am i doing. Please help

Comment: When I put your modal HTML inside the other HTML at the marked position, add the script, load the page, fill out the required text inputs and then click on "Save" button, the alert is showing.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$('#addNewCPModal').on('submit','#enterCPDetails',function(){
   alert("Hello");
});
```

Should Work.